# How to reduce high RAM usage of 2D sprites in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite, game-development

We ran into very high RAM usage with our project. We use java, libgdx and many sprites.

We wanted to upgrade our sprites to 81 frames of 512x512 as png, and since our entities are combined sprites (body, head, hair, weapon, clothes) and we want to give some variation with a number of entities at a time we talk about 500-1000 of those sprites that might be used (in extreme cases) parallel/quickly after each other. We tried with a few (~10) of those sprites and it used 6+GB RAM, so it's out of the question way too much.

We have now downsized the resolution to 128x128 (though we'd prefer 256) and the number of frames to 25 (which means more repetetive animation). We've looked into some methods of further reducing the ram usage but are not sure what methods work well.

project description: tilemap for static objects + additional entity stage. We expect to see up to 30 or so entities (x5 sprites) at a time on the screen when zooming out, still a few when zooming in.

Comment: How about reducing number of colors for sprites?

Comment: Has this question been solved yet?

Answer (score 1):

One way, if you haven't already done it, would be to put all the sprites in one image (sprite sheet), [like this](http://craftyjs.com/images/glitch_walker.png).

This reduces the amount of metadata required and the number of separate loaded images therefore RAM usage would also decrease. Then all you need is a sprite sheet loader, many examples can be found with a simple google search.

Another way would be to not load all your sprites together, only the ones that you need for each level or equivalent.

You must have an awful lot of sprites to use that much RAM. I would check your code to make sure that you aren't loading them multiple times by accident. The most common way of doing this is having loading code in the game loop.

Also, for each type of entity, only load the sprites once in the static context.